# IBM Worklight - BusyIndicator text value cannot be substituted with a variable?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-runtime

I am trying to substitute the text value in the constructor of the busyindicator with a variable rather hardcoding it. But for some reason the app is not able to understand the variable...

```
function wlCommonInit(){
    var locale = "Caricamento";
    var busyIndicator = new WL.BusyIndicator('content',{text:locale}); 
    busyIndicator.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[WL.BusyIndicator's `text` option](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m5/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/apiref/r_wl_busyindicator.html) expect a `string`, so you may not place a variable.

Instead, use `WL.ClientMessages`. For example:

```
var busy;

function wlCommonInit(){
    WL.ClientMessages.loading = "טוען...";
    busy = new WL.BusyIndicator();
    busy.show();
}
```

Reading material:

- [Enabling Translation](ftp://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v505/Module_15_-_Enabling_Translation.pdf) training module, slide #8

Comment: Idan, And that works fine.. Since it was a JSON Object I assumed a normal key value pair should work but now using WL.ClientMessages to achieve the same